# Posicion de dato mayor dentro de una matriz

Tags: python, matriz

```
filas = int(input("Introduce numero de filas: "))
columnas = int(input("Introduce numero de columnas: "))

matriz = []
for i in range(filas):
    matriz.append([0] * columnas)
    
for i in range(filas):
    for j in range(columnas):
        matriz[i][j] = int(input("Fila {}, columna {} : " .format(i+1, j+1)))
        
mayor = max(matriz)
print("El numero mayor de la matriz es: ")
print(mayor)
print("La matriz es:")
print(matriz)
```

Esto es lo que llevo, me muestra el dato mayor pero dentro de la matriz, y no muesta la posicion

Comment: Si quieres saber las coordenadas del máximo de la matriz, tienes que buscarlas tu mismo, recorriendo la matriz elemento a elemento, buscando el mayor y anotando las coordenadas cuando lo encuentres.

Comment: La función `max` te devuelve una fila completa (una lista), no un valor entero.

Answer (score 1):

La función `max` aplicada a una lista de listas retorna completa una de las sublistas, no el mayor valor escalar contenido en alguna de ellas.

```
>>>max([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
Out[8]: [3, 4]
```

La función `index` aplicada a una lista de listas retorna el índice de la sublista (retorna un entero, no un par de enteros):

```
>>>a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>>b = max(a)
>>>a.index(b)
Out[14]: 1
```

Por tanto, hay que recorrer trabajosamente la matriz buscando el mayor valor escalar y guardando los indices del valor encontrado.

La forma más rápida es hacer la busqueda junto con el ingreso;
cada vez que encuentra un valor mayor que el resto, anota fila y columna.

```
filas = int(input("Introduce numero de filas: "))
columnas = int(input("Introduce numero de columnas: "))

matriz = []
for i in range(filas):
    matriz.append([0] * columnas)

mayor = None  # Mayor valor encontrado hasta el momento.
fila = 0      # Fila de `mayor`
columna = 0   # Columna de `mayor`
for i in range(filas):
    for j in range(columnas):
        matriz[i][j] = int(input("Fila {}, columna {} : ".format(i + 1, j + 1)))
        if mayor is None: # Inicializamos mayor aqui.
            mayor = matriz[i][j] - 1
        if matriz[i][j] > mayor:
            mayor = matriz[i][j]
            fila = i
            columna = j

print("El numero mayor de la matriz es: ")
print(mayor)
print("Fila", fila + 1, ", columna", columna + 1)
print("La matriz es:")
print(matriz)
```

produce

```
Introduce numero de filas: 2
Introduce numero de columnas: 2
Fila 1, columna 1 : 0
Fila 1, columna 2 : 1
Fila 2, columna 1 : 2
Fila 2, columna 2 : 3
El numero mayor de la matriz es: 
3
Fila 2 , columna 2
La matriz es:
[[0, 1], [2, 3]]
```